# spinner is not giving me desired output

Tags: android

```
final Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
                        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {


                                spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
                                List  list = new ArrayList ();
                                list.add("Diabetes");
                                list.add("cancer");
                                list.add("HIV/AIDS");
                                list.add("Tuberculosis");
                                list.add("respiratory disease");
                                list.add("Coronary Artery");
                                ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
                                dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                 spinner1.getSelectedItemPosition();

                                if (list.equals("Diabetes")){
                                    int x ;
                                    int c ;

                                    x = z-5;
                                  c = 2016 + x;

                                    editText3.setText((name + " you might die in the year " + c) + "");
```

edit 1 - the program is working (executing perfectly ) but the spinner functionality is not working as desired . help me out .i am creating a death calculator in which user have to enter his age then he have to select from the spinner (which contains the disease names ) .
now that spinner is not working (the program is running and executing but the spinner functionality is not working

```
 button.setOnClickListener(
            new Button.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {

                    CheckBox yes = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.yes);
                    CheckBox no = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.no);
                    EditText ageText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ageText);
                    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
                    final EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);


                    final String name = editText.getText().toString();


                    if (yes.isChecked()) {
                        int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
                        int c;
                        c = age - 7;
                       final int z;
                         z = 2016 + c;

                        editText3.setText((name + " you might die in the year " + z) + "");

                    } else if (no.isChecked()) {
                        final int age = Integer.parseInt(ageText.getText().toString());
                        int c;

                        c = age + 10;
                        final int z;
                        z = 2016 + c;
                        editText3.setText((name + " you might die in the year " + z) + "");
```

this is button listener it would be helpful for you to give me the solutions .

regards

Comment: it would be better if you can let us know the issue you are facing as well. merely posting the code won't help us in figuring out the issue that we don't even know

Comment: Please describe more cleary, what the current behaviour of `spinner` is and what is should be.

Comment: look for edit 1 please dont degrade the question i would get blocked again .@MukeshRana 
@MartinZabel

Comment: I didn't downvoted your question. Anyway, I'm not familiar with this `Spinner` interface. But, you added the `Spinner` items in the event handler which get called when the user already selected an item from the `Spinner`. I think, this is to late. You presumably have to add the items during creation of the `Spinner`.

Answer (score 0):

Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

```
    List list = new ArrayList();
    list.add("Diabetes");
    list.add("cancer");
    list.add("HIV/AIDS");
    list.add("Tuberculosis");
    list.add("respiratory disease");
    list.add("Coronary Artery");
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            if (list.get(position).equalsIgnoreCase("Diabetes")) {
                int x;
                int c;
                x = z - 5;
                c = 2016 + x;

                editText3.setText((name + " you might die in the year " + c) + "");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: use equals instead of equalsIgnoreCase. And declear list as final or global

Comment: still same error :(

`  if (list.get(position).equals("Diabetes")) `